# SSMS SQL Server 2014 - Selecting BackupSets for a Restore takes a long time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, restore

I'm having an issue with SSMS SQL Server 2014 (before and after SP1).

When I go and select 'restore database' from the server and select a database, it just sits there and spin and spins. More than 24 hours with no results during one initial test.

**Test's I've done:**

Tested against the same database using both SSMS 2008 R2 and 2014/SP1 both on the server and on my laptop.

**Using SSMS SQL Server 2014:**

7 days in MSDB backupfile 1.9 mil records didn't finish in the time I took lunch.

After purging...

3 days in MSDB backupfile 767k records took 1 minute 31 seconds.

**Using SSMS SQL Server 2008 R2:**

90 days in msdb dbo.backupfile 6.7 mil records was instant and finished loading in less than 3 seconds.

I ran a trace while testing using both versions against both databases...

- When SSMS 2014 was executing the trace files would grow to almost 500MB...
- When SSMS 2008R2 was executing the trace file grew to 260k

I've also applied various indexes to the msdb database from other posts online. It helped a little when the records were reduced, but not enough to the desired effect.

So, in conclusion I think it might be 2014 SSMS that is the issue...thoughts?

Comment: Well I think the underlying issue is that you're retaining way too much backup history. SSMS not handling it is more of a symptom than a problem IMHO. :-)

Comment: Ola Hallengrens maintenance scripts include a SQL Agent Job that will keep MSDB clean and help to prevent these issues

Comment: @Aaron, I would agree with you except it works fine in SSMS 2008 R2 without any slowness.

Comment: @James, we are cleaning up now using the default msdb cleanup, but thanks I'll check his cleanup scripts.

Comment: Think you're still missing my point.

Comment: 90 days, 30 days, 7 days, 3 days, still didn't matter, still was slow. The trace produced almost 500MB of transactions to load 3 days worth for 2014. 2008, only 260k of transactions for the same database/server. Something isn't the same, something seems wrong.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, while I see your point and reducing the history will likely fix the issues, in the past, I've stored years of backup history and never had this problem when using the SSMS restore utility. I just did a test using SSMS 2008R2 and the restore was stitched together for me in less than a minute. Using SSMS 2014, after 2 hours it was still going. The message at the top right says "Creating restore plan: Selecting backupsets". Something has clearly changed in the way SSMS is doing its thing. I'm guessing it has something to do with the Timeline feature.

Comment: To add to the problem, there is no way to stop the restore without killing the SSMS process itself.

Comment: @Gizmo, glad I'm not the only one who has experienced this now. Now, if we can get a fix for this it would be nice.

Comment: I've seen this problem consistently for a few years now -- and we're always running the latest & greatest version of SSMS. Anyone got any solutions?   (Just checked our msdb.dbo.backupfile table - only 123k rows).